How are two Cuckoo hashing tables able to store more items than a single hashing table of double the size?
I specialize in deep learning and learned about Cuckhoo hashing from a blog post that said TikTok uses Cuckoo hashing in its large-scale recommender system to reduce the memory footprint of its user and video ID embeddings.
From what I understand, Cuckoo hashing iteratively slots items in two tables until it finds an empty slot. It's not clear to me how two tables has more capacity than a single table though.
Maybe I misunderstand the premise though. Is increasing the capacity of the system's collisionless hashes not one of Cuckoo hashing's primary benefits?

these Standford slides says of two-table cuckoo hashing "...load factor of less than ½.  At higher load factors, cuckoo hashing tends to perform dramatically worse and frequently needs to rehash."  More tables: "[with] 3,it's only around α = 0.91 that you run into trouble".  So, two-table cuckoo hashing doesn't generally work well for high load factors, which is what you want to reduce hash table memory footprint.  I haven't read the blog, but seems dubious.  HTH.
